# Could table-returning select Oracle query from stored procedure be transformed into LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, oracle

Could this Oracle query:`select * from table(some_stored_procedure(someParameter => :someValue)`

be transformed into LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the question.

If you mean to ask if you can run LinqToSql on Oracle, the answer is that there is no native support for Oracle, but there are some compatibility layers available, such as [DevArt DotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/).

If you mean to ask if you can turn a `DataSet` or `DataTable` into a Linq query, the answer is yes.  Assuming you have a `DataTable` called `dt` with your data in it:

```
var q = DataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => new { Column1 = r["Col1"], Column2 = r["Col2"] });
```

You get the idea...

Comment: I know about the latter, but sounds like your former is what I need.